# Can't find clientId in Commande for @ToOne relation

Tags: android, android-studio, orm, entity-relationship, greendao

Here is my first class :

```
@Entity(
    active = true,
    nameInDb = "CLIENTS"
)
public class Client {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String nom;
    @NotNull
    private String prenom;
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "commandeId")
    private List<Commande> listeCommandes;
}
```

My second one :

```
@Entity(
    active = true,
    nameInDb = "COMMANDES"
)
public class Commande {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String libelle;
    @NotNull
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "clientId")
    private Client client;
}
```

When i do a "Make Project" i have this error message :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:greendao'.
>   Can't find clientId in Commande for @ToOne relation

It appears that i have a problem with the relationship between my classes but i don't know how to resolve it. The GreenDAO documentation isn't enought explicit concerning relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the answer.

The first class :

```
@Entity(
    active = true,
    nameInDb = "CLIENTS"
)

public class Client {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String nom;
    @NotNull
    private String prenom;
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "clientId")
    private List<Commande> listeCommandes;
}
```

Second class :

```
@Entity(
    active = true,
    nameInDb = "COMMANDES"
)
public class Commande {
    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String libelle;
    @NotNull
    private long clientId;
    @NotNull
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "clientId")
    private Client client;
}
```